# php preventing max execution time limit for mail

Tags: php

I've a script to send packages of 300-500 e-mails hour. That means that this script will be fired once a hour using cron or other feature.

The server has a max execution limit of 30secs and it's not configurable.

I've been thinking if the pseudo-code below should work:

```
$time=time();
$count=0;
while(condition){
    $count++;
    send(email);
    $now=time();
    if($now-$time>=29){break;} //1sec margin
}
echo "$count e-mails sent";
```

Opinions?

Comment: So I'm assuming you can't utilize `ini_set('max_execution_time', 300)`?

Comment: I don't want to start a useless discussion. And if those are your parameters then so be it.... but sending 10k mails/day plus being limited to such a restrictive php environment sounds a bit like a mismatch to me ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to double-check that you can't set the execution time, here are two suggestions.

---

You could simply call `set_time_limit()` before sending an e-mail. According to the [PHP docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php):

> When called, set_time_limit() restarts the timeout counter from zero. In other words, if the timeout is the default 30 seconds, and 25 seconds into script execution a call such as set_time_limit(20) is made, the script will run for a total of 45 seconds before timing out.

For instance:

```
foreach ($emails as $email) {
    set_time_limit(30);
    send($email, ...);
}
```

---

Another option is via the cron. Since you are running PHP from a cron job, you can [specify your own `php.ini`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php). You could execute your script as follows:

```
php -c /custom/directory/my_php.ini my_script.php
```

Where `my_php.ini` may specify:

```
max_execution_time = 0     ; (unlimited)
```

Comment: The time limit is not configurable in his case.

Answer (score 5):

if your script is launched with cron it means that you're using PHP-CLI "PHP Command Line Interface".

As mentioned in the [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.php), your have no time limit while using CLI.

So you don't have to worry about that : `max_execution_time` is set to `unlimited`.

Comment: Exactly! The script shouldn't time out when being run from the shell.

Answer (score 0):

Break up the task in smaller chunks. Use the database to keep "state" of the actual job execution.

This approach has the advantage of being **scalable**: you probably will end-up having to send more emails as you grow, won't you?

Comment: Well. The question is "How small should it be?". My subscribe list has almost 50.000 entries. And the e-mails/hour limit is set by my host. What i'm guessing is if php is able to fire at least 300 per execution.

Comment: @Paulo: ok, I understand better the situation you are facing.  Anyhow, you'll need a strategy to deal with exceptions: that's when keeping a context in a permanent store kicks in.