# Set maximum execution time for exec() specifically

Tags: php, exec

Is it possible to set maximum execution time of `exec($command)` function? Sometimes execution of my `$command` lasts too long stopping after 1 minute and presenting this error:

> Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 60 seconds exceeded in C:\xampp\htdocs\files.php  on line 51

How can I increase the `exec()` command maximum execution time?

```
    if (allow()) {
    exec($command);

    if (file_exists($file)) {
        //exec($makeflv);
        echo '<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">window.top.window.aviout(1);</script>';

    } else {
        echo $error;
        }

} else {
   echo $error;
   }
```

Comment: Btw, this has been answered at least three times: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1176497/limit-execution-time-of-an-function-or-command-php, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1928249/php-preventing-max-execution-time-limit-for-mail and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2147567/avoid-php-execution-time-limit

Answer (score 21):

See http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php

```
set_time_limit($seconds)
```

If `$second` is set to `0`, no time limit is imposed. Note that you should be cautious with removing the time limit altogether. You don't want any infinite loops slowly eating up all server resources. A high limit, e.g. `180` is better than no limit.

Alternatively, you can adjust the time setting just for certain blocks of code and resetting the time limit after the time critical code has run, e.g.

```
$default = ini_get('max_execution_time');
set_time_limit(1000);
... some long running code here ...
set_time_limit($default);
```

Comment: ok i put set_time_limit(180) before exec($command); 
It seems to work!

but after the time expires i want to echo a error how i do this??

Comment: It will throw an error by itself when the time limit expires. That's what made you ask your question in the first place. If you want a custom error handler, see http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php

Comment: yes, but when i submit a form a process.php page start with a iframe, i only whant to echo this: <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">window.top.window.aviout('$result');</script> where the result is a error or succes!

Comment: If `set_error_hander` doesn't help, then I'm afraid I don't understand. Consider opening a new question, as it is a different problem.

Comment: I hope `set_time_limit(0)` overrides the maximum execution time for the current call?

Comment: @SuhailGupta for the entire *request*.

Answer (score 4):

In `.htaccess` you can set these values:

```
php_value max_execution_time 1000000
php_value max_input_time 1000000
```

You can also try this at the top of your PHP script:

```
set_time_limit(0);
```

Answer (score 3):

you can use [`ini_set()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php) like this:

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);
```

Setting it to 0 will make your script run forever according to the [documentation of the ini-directive](http://php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-execution-time).

Comment: how i can include ini_set() in my function?

Comment: Insert the line wherever you like. No magic involved.