# Opencart Extension Installation issue

Tags: opencart

Facing this problem while installing opencart extension at localhost

[image]

Comment: Have you look at this answer already - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2202355/set-maximum-execution-time-for-exec-specifically ?

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is related with in correct ftp details or no ftp details added in

Admin - System - Settings - Store - Edit - Ftp

You can contact your host for FTP details.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to update max_execution_time = 120 value in your php.ini file.

Or

You can add a php.ini file with max_execution_time = 120 value in /admin folder.

Or

You can add below code to .htaccess file too:

php_value max_execution_time 120

This will surely resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Use "FTP QuickFix" by iSense.

https://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=marketplace/extension/info&extension_id=18892

This extension allows install extension without FTP settings. It could be helpful if you have any FTP-related error by extension installation.

You need to download and unzip this mod first. 
Then, admin panel > Extensions > Extension Installer. 
Click the Upload button and select the .xml file that you previously unzipped. Navigate to Extensions > Modifications and click on the Refresh button at the top right corner of the screen. 
This is it.