# Request timing out when trying to upload file

Tags: laravel, guzzle

I'm trying to use Guzzle to make a post request,send some parameters and a file but when i run the application i get a timeout error

I've tried removing the file from the parameters and the request was sent normally

Error:

```php
Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalErrorException (E_UNKNOWN)
Maximum execution time of 60 seconds exceeded
```

Code that makes the request

```php
$client = new GuzzleHttp\Client();
  $res = $client->sendAsync('post', 'http://api.ocr.space/Parse/Image',[
    'headers' => [
      'apikey' => 'helloworld',
    ],
    'multipart' => [
      [
        'name'     => 'language',
        'contents' => 'por',
      ],
      [
        'name'     => 'filetype',
        'contents' => 'png',
      ],
      [
        'name'     => 'file',
        'contents' => fopen(asset('/public/Screenshot_2.png'), 'r'),
        'filename' => 'file.png'
      ]
    ]
  ]);
  $content = json_decode($res->getBody(), true);

  dd($content);
```

Comment: Can you add the code that doesn't work?

Comment: @AdityaThakur Added

Comment: Try increasing the execution time in php.ini, also if you can add post request code which has file input. It would help. Increase execution time https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2202355/set-maximum-execution-time-for-exec-specifically

Comment: @AdityaThakur I don't think it would help with a file that is just 94kb

Comment: sorry my bad, but can you add the code in which you've file parametes?

Comment: @AdityaThakur Oh sorry i've put the wrong code. Just updated

Comment: can you do `'contents' => fopen(asset('/public/Screenshot_2.png'), 'r') or die('not able to open file'),`

Comment: @AdityaThakur Done. Nothing changed, just timed out

Comment: since you are in laravel are you using php artisan serve or apache?

Comment: @AdityaThakur I'm using artisan serve

Comment: you might wanna take a look at this https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/code-review/file-upload-using-guzzle-client

Comment: @AdityaThakur Now i'm getting File does not exist at path http://localhost:8000/Screenshot_2.png . But when i put the url in the browser it gives me the file

Comment: @AdityaThakur Can you make the Answer based on your suggestion? So i can mark it as accepted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please Update your Max Execution Time in your php.ini file, also PHP server can cause issue's with post requests try switch to apache or xamp server. For more info: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/code-review/file-upload-using-guzzle-client

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps try to update your php.ini file.

1. Open terminal
2. type 'php --ini'
3. Open the loaded configuration

   ini_set('max_execution_time', x)

Replace x with the desired time in seconds (i.e. 120)

Comment: That's not gonna help, the file a i want to upload is just 94Kb